# How to check Sampling rate of .pcm files?

Tags: gstreamer, pcm

I am converting a .wav file to .pcm file using gstream, i need to verify the sampling rate of .pcm file after converting. Which tool can i use for this?Or is there any way to check it?Sorry if its a wrong question.

Already i tried with sox tool, but it doesn't support .pcm format. Please help me with this. Below is an example

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.wav ! wavparse ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,format=S16BE,channels=1,rate=8000 ! filesink location=file.pcm
```

**UPDATE** : PCM files sampling rate cannot be checked using any tools, "Audacity" software can be used to import the raw samples and set the sampling rate. We can check by listening to the actual audio with the converted audio and verify whether the sampling rate converted is ok.

Comment: No one supports `.pcm` just as it is. It is raw data so no tool can know the sample rate. You can play it and manually setting the sample rate and listen to it if it sounds okay..

Comment: Did you watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqjvB_VxMRM)?

Answer (score 2):

PCM files are plain raw files without any header so it is not possible to detect the sampling rate. You need sampling rate, channels, etc to be set in header which is what WAV format does. 
Equivalent of PCM in Audio,is YUV in video or RGB in image. Neither of them have any header. It is upto the user to parse them with desired sample rate, resolution, format etc and make meaningful buffers out of them